# yarn dev が実行されない

Tags: json, reactjs

Couldn't find a package.json fileと表示される

```
study-react % yarn dev

yarn run v1.22.19
error Couldn't find a package.json file in "/Users/kazu/study-react"
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

node -v
v18.12.1
yarn -v
1.22.19
npm -v
8.19.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/Users/kazu/study-react/package.json

というファイルを作っておいてはいかがでしょう

中身は空のJSONとかで

```
{}
```